# Symfony 3.4 - Alias a service to an interface, deprecation message

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm migrating my Symfony application from 2.8 to 3.4 (then to 4.1) and I get this deprecation message in profiler.

Does anyone know how to I fix it?

> Autowiring services based on the types they implement is deprecated
>   since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported in version 4.0. You should
>   alias the "**Core\Infrastructure\Utils\TokenGenerator**" service to
>   "**Core\Application\Utils\TokenGenerator**" instead.

In my **services.yml** I have

```
Core\Infrastructure\Utils\TokenGenerator:
     arguments: ["@logger"]

app.token_generator: '@Core\Infrastructure\Utils\TokenGenerator'
```

In my code the class `Core\Infrastructure\Utils\TokenGenerator implements Core\Application\Utils\TokenGenerator` interface

Comment: In your code you have a type hint against the TokenGenerator interface.  Which is fine.  The autowire is trying to wire this service which means your app.token_generator is irrelevant.  You need to either exclude the class which uses TokenGenerator from autowire or just go ahead and add an alias as the message suggests.  Better yet, replace app.token_generator with the interface name.  Autowire works well but can do some surprising things when first encountered.

Comment: ok. I will try your suggestions. thank you.